# How to find the n largest files in a folder?

Tags: command-line, files, disk-usage

How to find the n largest files in a folder except the ones from the first folder?

In this example, for **n=2**:

```
dir
--file 50KB
--dir1
--dir2
----file2_1.txt (size 25KB)
--dir3
----dir3_1
------file3_1.txt (size 35KB)
------file3_2 (size 25KB)
```

Result:

```
dir/dir3/dir3_1/file3_1.txt 35KB
dir/dir2/file2_1.txt 25KB
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find . -mindepth 2 -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -n | cut -f 2- | tail -n $n
```

Here, the largest file is last. If you want to change the order so the largest file is first:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -nr | cut -f 2- | head -n $n
# .............................................^...............^^^^
```

---

With the GNU toolset, you can handle filenames that contain newlines (annoying but valid):

```bsh
find . -mindepth 2 -printf "%s\t%p\0" | sort -znr | cut -zf 2- | head -zn $n
```

---

And to get your desired output, you can do:

```bsh
find . -mindepth 2 -printf "%s\t%p\n" |
  sort -nr |
  head -n 5 |
  perl -MNumber::Bytes::Human=format_bytes -F'\t' -lane '
    push @F, format_bytes(shift @F);
    print join "\t", @F;
  '
```

Using perl module [Number::Bytes::Human](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Number::Bytes::Human) from CPAN.

Comment: To get the OP's *exact* desired output would require `sort -k1,1nr | cut -f 2- | head -n $n` I think (otherwise `dir/dir3/dir3_1/file3_2.txt` will sort above the equally-sized `dir/dir2/file2_1.txt`

Answer (score 5):

Although you tagged your question `bash`, here is a `zsh` solution in case others find it useful.

Given

```
% tree -h dir
dir
├── [ 512]  dir1
├── [ 512]  dir2
│   └── [ 25K]  file2_1.txt
├── [ 512]  dir3
│   └── [ 512]  dir3_1
│       ├── [ 35K]  file3_1.txt
│       └── [ 25K]  file3_2.txt
└── [ 50K]  file

4 directories, 4 files
```

then using `zsh` with *glob qualifiers*:

```
% print -RC1 dir/*/**/*(.OLon[1,2])
dir/dir3/dir3_1/file3_1.txt
dir/dir2/file2_1.txt
```

where

- `dir/*/` ensures we start at least 1 directory below `dir`, equivalent of `find`'s `-mindepth`
- `**/*` is a shell glob that matches recursively (the same is available in `bash` if the `globstar` option is set)
- `()` encloses a collection of qualifiers, specifically

  - `.` matches regular files only (equivalent of `find -type f`)
  - `OL` orders the results by size (**L**ength) descending, while `on` breaks ties by **n**ame ascending
  - `[1,2]` selects a range of results

Unlike `find`, shell globs generally omit hidden files by default - if you want to include them, add `D` to the qualifiers i.e. `(.DOLon[1,2])`

Comment: In `[1,2]` can you put a variable in there? `[1,$n]`?

Comment: @glennjackman yes it seems like you can

Answer (score 2):

From the top of my head:

```sh
ls -lsR * | awk '{print $6,$10}'| sort -nr | head -n5
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: If you want something for simple interactive use, `ls -lhrSd ** | tail -5` works well.  (To sort by apparent file size, not usage.) `**` is bash extglob recursive expansion of all files and directories, hence the `-d`.  IDK why you're using `-s` to print disk usage if you're not even going to extract that with awk

Answer (score 1):

```
# find . -type f -exec du -s {} \; | sort -h -t1 | tail -n 10
```

who shorter?, by theway - in Larsson's version - only cur directory is used... not count.

Anyway, if u would to restrict level, you could restrict it by `find -maxdepth`

e.g.

```
# find  . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec du -s {} \; | sort -h -t1 | tail -n 10
```

If you would to exclude first level, than you might use `mindepth 2`, `maxdepth whatever`...

Answer (score 0):

Kindly run below one liner with your required-path. as of now i am running for  `/var/log/` location

```
 (sudo  du -a /var/log/ |sort -nr|head -n20 |awk '{print $NF}'|while read l ;do du -csh $l|grep -vi total;done ) 2> /dev/null
```